# Correct "empty" return value for List[List[X]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, null

If I have a function `List[A] => List[List[A]]` and need to return an "empty" value, is there a theoretical preference between the following

a) `Nil`

b) `List(Nil)`

... or does it depend on the function?

For a concrete example, I could implement a function to split a list into sublists of length `n` or less as follows:

```
def sublists[A](xs: List[A], n: Int): List[List[A]] = {
  val (ys, zs) = xs.splitAt(n)
  if (zs.isEmpty) ys :: Nil
  else            ys :: sublists(zs, n)
}
```

If `xs` is empty this returns `List(Nil)`. Do I need to include a check on whether `xs` is empty, returning `Nil`, for this function to be correct?

Comment: I'd pretty strongly prefer to get `Nil` in that case, but I suspect it depends on the function.

Comment: In this case I would interpret `List(Nil)` as a single empty sublist. That's obviously wrong as all sublist should have length `n`.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt No, `n` _or less_.

Comment: @Robin I see. Still I'd say `Nil` would be the correct result. If you pass an `xs` containing `2*n` elements, you get a list with two elements as result. If `xs` contains `n` elements, you get a list with one element. So, naturally, if `xs` is empty, you should get a list with no elements, i.e., `Nil`.

Comment: Empty list is an empty list. `List(Nil)` is a `List` containing an empty list. Just stick to the basic definition of empty list, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doubt, the correct empty value for a List is the empty List, no matter what the type of the List elements is.

The same is true for more elaborated types. A set containing the empty set is very different from an empty set, and so forth.

Think of it like this: A list result allows you to ask: how many results do we have? If you use a list with an empty List as empty value, then the answer would be incorrectly 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with `Nil`, aka `List()`.  For example,

```
sublists(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil), 2)
```

returns

```
List(1 :: 2 :: Nil, 3 :: 4 :: Nil)
```

and not

```
List(1 :: 2 :: Nil, 3 :: 4 :: Nil, Nil)
```

The terminal `Nil` is usually chopped off.  So for consistency I would keep `sublists(Nil)  ->   List()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context, so I don't feel comfortable being definitive. In general, I think the answer is context-dependent. In the abstract, I'd definitely prefer Nil as a client-code writer - in writing a closure over the results, I don't think I'd be expecting an empty sublist.

Rearranging to put the null-check before the splitAt will do the trick.

Comment: I'm the man who downvoted you. You're saying quite obvious things, but don't provide explanations of *why* (do X because of Y, otherwise do A because of B).